# Suppress proxy generation for some hubs or methods

Tags: javascript, proxy, signalr

I'm starting out with SignalR and I have a situation where I'm going to have a SignalR site that will be broadcasting messages to clients, but I also need an admin interface that will actually trigger those messages. The admin page will call server side methods that will, in turn, call client side Javascript methods for regular users. So I'm thinking I can either set up two separate hubs (one for admin, one for everybody else) or I can have methods in a single hub that can only be called by the admin that will check authorization.

But in addition to the authorization, I'd like to have SignalR not include admin methods or an admin hub in the generated Javascript proxy classes so that I'm not advertising their existence (again - this is NOT the only security, I will be checking authorization). Is there an attribute or property I can set on individual hubs or on methods within a hub that will suppress them from being included in the proxy (but still have them callable from Javascript)? I know you can set `EnableJavaScriptProxies` to `false` in your `HubConfiguration`, but that seems to be global and I'd like to keep the proxy for the stuff I do want the regular client to be using.

Comment: Not sure if there is an equivalent in the SignalR generator, but it may be possible to use [ProxyAPI](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/11/06/proxyapi-automatic-javascript-proxies-for-webapi-and-mvc/) as a generator, which lets you [ProxyExclude] methods

Comment: One option would be to use signalr.exe to generate your proxies at build time and edit the output.

Comment: @el_tone: Yeah, I was thinking that too. It might not be too complicated for this particular project (it's not very large), but for more complicated projects, that would be a huge pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a way of excluding specific methods from the proxy today. You'd have to re-implement your own proxy generator that basically does what we do in our default impl but has knowledge of some attribute to skip generation of specific methods.

We can conceivable add this in a future version of SignalR. File an issue on github if you feel strongly about having this.

Here's the default implementation (it would have been easier if we made more methods virtual and non static).

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs

Comment: Thanks David. It does seem like something that would be useful to have. For the time being I might just grab the generated proxy, manually edit it and then add back as a static class. Of course, that will get really annoying if I later need to change my hub.

Answer (score 8):

There is one trick using interfaces. As proxy will generate only public methods in proxy, you can create hub using interface like this:

```
public class MyHub : Hub, IMyHub
{
    void IMyHub.NotGeneratedOnClient()
    {
    }

    public void GeneratedOnClient()
    {
    }
}
```

NotGeneratedOnClient method will not be visible if you use object of type MyHub, you can access it only using interface. As method is not public proxy generator is not going to add it to client proxy

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.  While I don't see the method in the proxy, I also cannot call it manually using Invoke( ).  Marking it private or protected seems to have the same effect.  I am looking into deriving the ReflectedMethodDescriptorProvider (really, no virtual functions!?!?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified **DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator** with the following changes:

1. It will exclude functions from Javascript proxy generation with a new **[HubMethodExcludeFromProxy]** attribute.
2. The *private static* functions have changed to *protected virtual* for future derivatives.
3. The *GenerateProxy( )* function has an overload to include DocComments, but that was not caching the results like the non DocComments version.  Now they both cache.
4. Two resources, *Resources.DynamicComment_CallsMethodOnServerSideDeferredPromise* and *Resources.DynamicComment_ServerSideTypeIs* were private to another assembly, so to get things to compile, I copied the text from the resource file directly.  These two resources are only used if DocComments is true.
5. All of the **DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator** references were changed to **CustomJavaScriptProxyGenerator** except for one, which is used to locate the resource script **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Scripts.hubs.js**, located in a different assembly.

First, you will need to update the dependency resolver to use the new **CustomJavaScriptProxyGenerator** for the IJavaScriptProxyGenerator interface.  If you are using the default resolver, you can set up a custom resolver like this:

```
map.RunSignalR(
    new HubConfiguration() {
        Resolver = new CustomDependencyResolver()
    }
);
```

And here is a custom resolver that derives from the DefaultDependecyResolver:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
{
    public class CustomDependencyResolver : DefaultDependencyResolver
    {
        MyDependencyResolver() : base()
        {
            var proxyGenerator = new Lazy(() => new CustomJavaScriptProxyGenerator(this));
            Register(typeof(IJavaScriptProxyGenerator), () => proxyGenerator.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the new **CustomJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs** file (the **HubMethodExcludeFromProxyAttribute** class is at the bottom):

```
// Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
// Mods by Brain2000
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs
{
    public class CustomJavaScriptProxyGenerator : IJavaScriptProxyGenerator
    {
        protected static readonly Lazy _templateFromResource = new Lazy(GetTemplateFromResource);

        protected static readonly Type[] _numberTypes = new[] { typeof(byte), typeof(short), typeof(int), typeof(long), typeof(float), typeof(decimal), typeof(double) };
        protected static readonly Type[] _dateTypes = new[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTimeOffset) };

        protected const string ScriptResource = "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Scripts.hubs.js";

        protected readonly IHubManager _manager;
        protected readonly IJavaScriptMinifier _javaScriptMinifier;
        protected readonly Lazy _generatedTemplate;
        protected readonly Lazy _generatedTemplateWithComments;

        public CustomJavaScriptProxyGenerator(IDependencyResolver resolver) :
            this(resolver.Resolve(),
                 resolver.Resolve())
        {
        }

        public CustomJavaScriptProxyGenerator(IHubManager manager, IJavaScriptMinifier javaScriptMinifier)
        {
            _manager = manager;
            _javaScriptMinifier = javaScriptMinifier ?? NullJavaScriptMinifier.Instance;
            _generatedTemplate = new Lazy(() => GenerateProxy(_manager, _javaScriptMinifier, includeDocComments: false));
            _generatedTemplateWithComments = new Lazy(() => GenerateProxy(_manager, _javaScriptMinifier, includeDocComments: true));
        }

        public string GenerateProxy(string serviceUrl)
        {
            serviceUrl = JavaScriptEncode(serviceUrl);
            return _generatedTemplate.Value.Replace("{serviceUrl}", serviceUrl);
        }

        public string GenerateProxy(string serviceUrl, bool includeDocComments)
        {
            if (!includeDocComments) return GenerateProxy(serviceUrl); //use the includeDocComments: false cached version

            serviceUrl = JavaScriptEncode(serviceUrl);
            return _generatedTemplateWithComments.Value.Replace("{serviceUrl}", serviceUrl);
        }

        protected virtual string GenerateProxy(IHubManager hubManager, IJavaScriptMinifier javaScriptMinifier, bool includeDocComments)
        {
            string script = _templateFromResource.Value;

            var hubs = new StringBuilder();
            var first = true;
            foreach (var descriptor in hubManager.GetHubs().OrderBy(h => h.Name))
            {
                if (!first)
                {
                    hubs.AppendLine(";");
                    hubs.AppendLine();
                    hubs.Append("    ");
                }
                GenerateType(hubManager, hubs, descriptor, includeDocComments);
                first = false;
            }

            if (hubs.Length > 0)
            {
                hubs.Append(";");
            }

            script = script.Replace("/*hubs*/", hubs.ToString());

            return javaScriptMinifier.Minify(script);
        }

        protected virtual void GenerateType(IHubManager hubManager, StringBuilder sb, HubDescriptor descriptor, bool includeDocComments)
        {
            // Get only actions with minimum number of parameters.
            var methods = GetMethods(hubManager, descriptor);
            var hubName = GetDescriptorName(descriptor);

            sb.AppendFormat("    proxies['{0}'] = this.createHubProxy('{1}'); ", hubName, hubName).AppendLine();
            sb.AppendFormat("        proxies['{0}'].client = {{ }};", hubName).AppendLine();
            sb.AppendFormat("        proxies['{0}'].server = {{", hubName);

            bool first = true;

            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
                if (!first)
                {
                    sb.Append(",").AppendLine();
                }
                GenerateMethod(sb, method, includeDocComments, hubName);
                first = false;
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.Append("        }");
        }

        protected virtual string GetDescriptorName(Descriptor descriptor)
        {
            if (descriptor == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("descriptor");
            }

            string name = descriptor.Name;

            // If the name was not specified then do not camel case
            if (!descriptor.NameSpecified)
            {
                name = JsonUtility.CamelCase(name);
            }

            return name;
        }

        protected virtual IEnumerable GetMethods(IHubManager manager, HubDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            return from method in manager.GetHubMethods(descriptor.Name).Where(md => md.Attributes.FirstOrDefault(a => (a.GetType() == typeof(HubMethodExcludeFromProxyAttribute))) == null)
                   group method by method.Name into overloads
                   let oload = (from overload in overloads
                                orderby overload.Parameters.Count
                                select overload).FirstOrDefault()
                   orderby oload.Name
                   select oload;
        }

        protected virtual void GenerateMethod(StringBuilder sb, MethodDescriptor method, bool includeDocComments, string hubName)
        {
            var parameterNames = method.Parameters.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendFormat("            {0}: function ({1}) {{", GetDescriptorName(method), Commas(parameterNames)).AppendLine();
            if (includeDocComments)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("            /// Calls the {0} method on the server-side {1} hub.\nReturns a jQuery.Deferred() promise.", method.Name, method.Hub.Name).AppendLine();
                var parameterDoc = method.Parameters.Select(p => String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "            /// Server side type is {2}", p.Name, MapToJavaScriptType(p.ParameterType), p.ParameterType)).ToList();
                if (parameterDoc.Any())
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, parameterDoc));
                }
            }
            sb.AppendFormat("                return proxies['{0}'].invoke.apply(proxies['{0}'], $.merge([\"{1}\"], $.makeArray(arguments)));", hubName, method.Name).AppendLine();
            sb.Append("             }");
        }

        protected virtual string MapToJavaScriptType(Type type)
        {
            if (!type.IsPrimitive && !(type == typeof(string)))
            {
                return "Object";
            }
            if (type == typeof(string))
            {
                return "String";
            }
            if (_numberTypes.Contains(type))
            {
                return "Number";
            }
            if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                return "Array";
            }
            if (_dateTypes.Contains(type))
            {
                return "Date";
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }

        protected virtual string Commas(IEnumerable values)
        {
            return Commas(values, v => v);
        }

        protected virtual string Commas(IEnumerable values, Func selector)
        {
            return String.Join(", ", values.Select(selector));
        }

        protected static string GetTemplateFromResource()
        {
            //this must remain "DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator" because the resource "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Scripts.hubs.js" lives there
            using (Stream resourceStream = typeof(DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ScriptResource))
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(resourceStream);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        protected virtual string JavaScriptEncode(string value)
        {
            value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);

            // Remove the quotes
            return value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2);
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class HubMethodExcludeFromProxyAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is all a decorator to your hub methods, such as:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    [HubMethodExcludeFromProxy]
    public void NotGeneratedOnClient()
    {
    }

    public void GeneratedOnClient()
    {
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : There is an issue with dependency injection where if you have two different instances of a resolver, one in the GlobalHost.DependencyResolver and one in the Signalr configuration, it will cause remote methods to sometimes not work.  Here is the fix:

```
//use only !ONE! instance of the resolver, or remote SignalR functions may not run!
var resolver = new CustomDependencyResolver();
GlobalHost.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
map.RunSignalR(
    new HubConfiguration() {
        Resolver = resolver;
    }
);
```

Reference: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2807

Answer (score 0):

I actually just changed the access modifier of the method to '**protected**' or '**internal**' and it just disappeared from the proxy on the client in

JS:

```
MyHub.connection.proxies.MyHub.server.TheMethod(); // TheMethod disappeared 
MyHub.server.TheMethod(); // TheMethod disappeared
```

Also If i call it via JS anyway, a js exception is thrown