# How to hide public methods in SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

**Is there any way to hide public methods in a singlar hub from the client? I'm not referring to authentication.** I don't want them to be generated at all for the client api. However, I want to be able to access them from other DLLs in my project (therefore I need to be public rather than internal). I have controller methods that I call into to perform various session lookups, and from the controller I want to call into my SignalR hub.

Comment: what do you mean with "hide"? based on what criterion do you want to hide? and what kind of client are you talking about? if you don't want signalr clients to access the code at all, why put it in a signalr hub method?

Comment: I have private collections that are inside the hub that need to be updated when certain things happen in the application. I want to be able to call the method from inside my application. I don't want the javascript for the method to get generated... The methods are tightly related to my hub but they aren't meant to be called from 'connected' clients.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  I need to utilize either a separate "superadmin" hub, or combine role security along with somehow "masking" selected methods from proxy generation.

Answer (score 1):

If the method should never be called by a client, then it should not be in the hub at all; I'd suggest extracting this logic from the hubs and using them as connectors only.

You can [disable the generated proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/introduction-to-security#autogen) in your hub configuration:

```
var config = new HubConfiguration
    {
        EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
    };
```

but this affects all methods and as far as I know cannot be customized per method at the moment (and the client can still call the method with invoke).

Comment: Looks like it is not possible per here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522489/suppress-proxy-generation-for-some-hubs-or-methods  >> Although there is a workaround using interfaces that looks like I can use to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used SignalR before, but I assume there is a Assembly file for the project. If so you could use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx).

Otherwise there is also [EditorBrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).